# Adaptive in Typescript not rendering adaptive card actions like hyperlinks, text bold, etc

Tags: typescript, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, teams-toolkit

The adaptive card JSON object is as shown below

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "So set **wrap** to true if you plan on showing a paragraph of text [Adaptive Cards](https://adaptivecards.io)",
                    "wrap": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Output in Teams app:

So set **wrap** to true if you plan on showing a paragraph of text [Adaptive Cards](https://adaptivecards.io)

Answer (score 0):

We have tested the given adaptive card json in App studio. It was working fine at our end.

[image]